# In CMake, how would one run a custom command only if any subdirectory needed to be rebuild

Tags: cmake

I have a CMake-based project, and I need to run a command after build, if anything changed, including in any subprojects.

Simplified structure

```
project_root/
  CMakeLists.txt (project root)
  executable_1/
    CMakeLists.txt (project tool1)
    library_1/
      CMakeLists.txt (project lib1)
  executable_2/
    CMakeLists.txt (project tool2)
    library_2/
      CMakeLists.txt (project lib2)
  library_3/
    CMakeLists.txt (project lib3)
```

The project root CMakeLists.txt looks like

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)

add_subdirectory(tool1)
add_subdirectory(tool2)
add_subdirectory(lib3)

project(root C)

add_custom_target(root ALL
    COMMENT
        "root target"
    DEPENDS
        ${DEPLOY_PATH}/deploy.tar.xz
)

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT
        ${DEPLOY_PATH}/deploy.tar.xz
    COMMAND
        tar cJf ${DEPLOY_PATH}/deploy.tar.xz *
    COMMENT
        "taring"
    DEPENDS
        root
)
```

The tool CMakeLists.txt look about like

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)

add_subdirectory(lib1)

project(tool1 C)

add_executable(tool1
    src/tool1.c
)

target_include_directories(tool1
    PRIVATE
        ./
)

target_link_libraries(tool1
    PRIVATE
        lib1
        lib3
)

install(TARGETS tool1 DESTINATION ${DEPLOY_PATH})
```

with the lib's CMakeLists.txt files omitting the `install` line and providing appropriate public include directories, etc.

I can get the behavior I want if I explicitly list every single subproject in the DEPENDS line of the custom target for "root", but that's tedious and error-prone. In the real project there are dozens of sub-libraries and executables.

I can also easily just re-build the archive every time, but that's slow.

How do I rebuild the archive if (and only if) any of the sub-projects of the root project or their descendants has changed?

Answer (score 0):

List the actual dependencies of the tool.

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE srcs *) # I hope that's correct
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT
        ${DEPLOY_PATH}/deploy.tar.xz
    COMMAND
        # * generally is invalid, * depends on shell filename expansion
        tar cJf ${DEPLOY_PATH}/deploy.tar.xz *  
    COMMENT "taring"
    DEPENDS ${srcs}
)
```

But that's wrong anyway - cmake is meant to be run once and it scans your tree once. If you add a new file, you'll have to reconfigure cmake. Rather consider building the archive only when you actually need it - when deploying.